# toggleClass not adding back the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically what I want to do is a simple toggleClass when a checkbox is click but the problem is it removes the class but its not adding back the class.

Here's a sample code:

```
$('#task-checkbox').click(function() {
   $(".dependent-task").toggleClass("dependent-task");
});
```

Full code here / jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stan255/qxJ5d/2/

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem here.

- Stanley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple. This line

```
$(".dependent-task").toggleClass("dependent-task");
```

removes the class 'dependent-task' from the element. So, the next time the checkbox is clicked, $('.depentend-task') is an empty jQuery object. To avoid that, store a reference to the jQuery object after page load:

```
var $dependentTask = $(".dependent-task");
$('#task-checkbox').click(function() {
   $dependentTask.toggleClass("dependent-task");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Oscar and James. It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Oscar Paz solution will work fine. If you don't want to keep a reference to the element, you could just define a different class for doing the color change. See this **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/qxJ5d/11/)**.

HTML:

```
<span class="dependent-task outstanding-task">
            Write 15 press release articles
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.outstanding-task {
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".dependent-task").toggleClass("outstanding-task");
```